# Why List Box items are not update during Filtering?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, filter

I`m writing a program to view product Information in a Listbox. I have a text box for searching that automatically filters the list as you typing by ProductName. I have run through my C# code numerous times and I can see the filter actually working but I cannot visually get it to filter or 'refresh' on the screen.

C# Code :

```
private ICollectionView _ProductInfoView;
    public ICollectionView ProductInfoView 
    {
        get{return this._ProductInfoView;}
        set
        {
            this._ProductInfoView=value;
            this.onPropertyChnage("ProductInfoView");
        }
    }

 private void RibbonSetupProduct_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.hidePanels();
        new Task(() =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ObservableCollection<ModelProductInformation> productInfoCollection   = new ObservableCollection<ModelProductInformation>(from ProductInfo in new GTS_ERPEntities().ProductInformations select new ModelProductInformation { ProductID = ProductInfo.ProductID,  ProductName = ProductInfo.ProductName , Remark=ProductInfo.Remark});
                this.ProductInfoView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(productInfoCollection);
                new ProductInfoSearch(ProductInfoView, this.TestTextBox);
            }
                ), DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
        }
        ).Start(); 

        this.PanelProducts.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

  class ProductInfoSearch
   {
      public ProductInfoSearch(ICollectionView filteredList, TextBox textEdit)
      {
        string filterText = string.Empty;

        filteredList.Filter = delegate(object obj)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
            {
                return true;
            }
            ModelProductInformation str = obj as ModelProductInformation;
            if (str.ProductName==null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (str.ProductName.ToUpper().Contains(filterText.ToUpper()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        };
        textEdit.TextChanged += delegate
        {
            filterText = textEdit.Text;
            filteredList.Refresh();
        };
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<dxe:ListBoxEdit x:Name="ProductInfoList" Margin="1.666,1,8,8" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5"  DisplayMember="ProductName" DataContext="{Binding ProductInfoView, ElementName=window}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

I guess my problem is either  Data Binding or inside Task().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would make the ObservableCollection a private field and just create the instance once and also just create the ICollectionView once. to add new data you can use clear and add on your Collection - try it, it works for me.

```
 private ObservableCollection<ModelProductInformation> productInfoCollection;

 //ctor, just once in the constructor
 this.productInfoCollection =  new ObservableCollection<ModelProductInformation>();
 this.ProductInfoView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(productInfoCollection);
 new ProductInfoSearch(ProductInfoView, this.TestTextBox);


private void RibbonSetupProduct_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.hidePanels();
    new Task(() =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var yourData = from ProductInfo in new GTS_ERPEntities().ProductInformations select new ModelProductInformation { ProductID = ProductInfo.ProductID,  ProductName = ProductInfo.ProductName , Remark=ProductInfo.Remark};
            //if you wanna change the collection, simple clear and add(or create AddRange extension)
           this.productInfoCollection.Clear();

           foreach(var data in yourData)
           { this.productInfoCollection.Add(data);}
        }
            ), DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
    }
    ).Start(); 

    this.PanelProducts.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: I remove Task stuff but it still not working.Please there is any other solution.

Comment: did you try instancing once and productInfoCollection as class member? i had some issues in the past when using local variables with ICollection like you did with productInfoCollection

Comment: I am solved my problem. The Problem was in List Box. I used Developer Express ListBoxEdit. It is not work. I don`t know why. Now I am use ListBox and work fine and your answer is also correct. Thank you.